# scrollbar not showing in edittext

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to add a box for entering text. This box should have a small scroll bar on the side. Using this piece of code, what I get is a blank line in which I can enter multiple lines of text. Would anyone know how I could get the box with a scrollbar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/event_description"
            android:hint="@string/hint_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#02960B"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditText inside scrollview will not show you the scroll bar. To show scroll bar for edittext use the following code in yout **EditText** field for this you don't need to use scrollview you can get rid of it.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

ScrollView can show scroll bar only if it contain more elements than its height size

**A typical Exampl of EditText with scrollbar:**

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_query"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

</EditText>
```